# Android Facebook SDK Remember Session

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

I'm writing an application which requires facebook login. I can make user log in when he/she first opens the application. However, I can't retrieve the session after they restart the application. My login code is the following:

```
private static Session openActiveSession(Activity activity, boolean allowLoginUI, StatusCallback callback, List<String> permissions) {
    OpenRequest openRequest = new OpenRequest(activity).setPermissions(permissions).setCallback(callback);
    Session session = new Session.Builder(activity).build();
    if (SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED.equals(session.getState()) || allowLoginUI) {
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        session.openForRead(openRequest);
        return session;
    }
    return null;
}
```

And I use `isLoggedIn` method when the app is opened in order to understand if the user is logged in or not.

```
public static boolean isLoggedIn() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But when the application is closed and reopened, this method never returns `true`.

How can I retrieve old session back **without** showing a popup window to want user's facebook account informations, if he/she logged in in the past.

Comment: are you closing the session anywhere?

Comment: No I'm not. if you are logged in before you close app, next openActiveSession method call opens the previous session without showing a login dialog. However, if you are not logged in, it opens a login dialog. There must be a way that I can know whether the user was logged in in previous app open, without showing a login dialog.

Comment: You can call Session.openActiveSessionFromCache, it will open the active session with a cached access token if it can, or return null if it cannot.

Comment: @MingLi thank you, if you write your comment as an answer, I'll check it as right answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call Session.openActiveSessionFromCache which will open the active session only if there's a cached access token, or return null otherwise.